# How to apply a php function with a button

Tags: php

I realized that the script I wrote is attempting to use both javascript and php, and this doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how I might go about achieve what I'm looking to do? What I want to do is have a button that when clicked, it will write to file on the server. Here;s the code i wrote:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
function change_html(){
     $myFile = "testFile.html";
     $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
     $stringData = "Hello\n";
     fwrite($fh, $stringData);
     $stringData = "World!\n";
     fwrite($fh, $stringData);
     fclose($fh);
     }
?>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="change_html()" Value="Continue">
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You'll need to use AJAX - using JavaScript to interact with server-side scripts, like this PHP script.

Comment: Go to your webpage, right click somewhere and click "View Source". Notice that the PHP code you wrote is not there. It ran on the server, and the output of that code is what was sent to the browser. That's how PHP and other server-side programming works. Your browser requests the webpage, the web server runs your code, and sends its output to the browser as the response. Clicking a link or submitting a form creates a new request to the server, a new opportunity to run code, like writing a file. When you wrote your question here on StackOverflow, you had to submit a form for SO to save it.

Comment: @Nightfirecat He doesn't *need* to use AJAX. Just because he confused JavaScript and PHP doesn't mean he had a requirement to do this asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in PHP, then you have your button submit a form and the PHP script it points to does the work.

```
<form action="writefile.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

-

```
<?php
//writefile.php
file_put_contents("testFile.html", "Hello\nWorld!\n");
?>
```

That script can redirect back to the form if you want:

```
<?php
//writefile.php
file_put_contents("testFile.html", "Hello\nWorld!\n");
header("Location: yourpage.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't do that. PHP is server side and JavaScript is client side. You have two options:

1. Use JS on the client to fire an AJAX call that hits a page which runs your script.
2. Have the button submit a form that runs your script.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to say

Comment: Are you going to answer his question using either of those two options? This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand what PHP and Javascript actually are: a server-side and client-side language. PHP only works on the server and can only communicate with the client through HTTP requests (so the browser or Ajax). Javascript on the other hand is a client-side language and can only works in the browsers windows, which means it can only modify the page. It can however, communicate with the server through Ajax requests.

You should read more about **what** PHP and Javascript actually are. Not to mention that your HTML-code absolutely doesn't validate.

When you understand what you are actually doing you should either create an Ajax request to a PHP script that modified the file or, you should add the input button the a form (which is actually mandatory) and point the form to a PHP script that modifies the file. I think the latter is the better way.

Comment: You should answer his question using one of those two ways. This isn't an answer to his question (how do I write a file when a button is clicked), but an extended comment.

Comment: @Dan Grossman: I don't think you should write a copy-and-paste solution to a question when it's as trivial as this. If Dave doesn't understand this, I don't think he'll be able to write good scripts, so Alex, jondavidjohn and myself point him in the right direction. If nobody would do that Dave would never learn how this actually works...

Comment: That's what the comments box is for. That's not what the answer box is for. This isn't a discussion forum.

Comment: But this site is no place to baby-sit and work-for-free for others neither. People ask questions here not only to get a quick answer, but also to understand why his/her original solution doesn't work and to learn something. In order to achieve that I believe you shouldn't give a finished answer when it's clear the asker has no idea what he's talking about.

Comment: Thanks Frog, I understand your frustration, but I think that maybe you shoud reevaluate why you check the forums!! Thanks for the help. Dan actually helped me with my dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['change_html'])) change_html();

function change_html(){
     $myFile = "testFile.html";
     $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
     $stringData = "Hello\n";
     fwrite($fh, $stringData);
     $stringData = "World!\n";
     fwrite($fh, $stringData);
     fclose($fh);
     }
?>
</head>
<body>
<form action="?change_html=true" method="GET">
<input type="submit" Value="Continue">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Gerry, Thanks for your help. This didn't quite work for me, but I'm 100% it had something to do with me!! Thanks again!